# How to set different colors for each tab in react native

Tags: react-native

In my app I'm creating a tab using TabViewAnimated. I need those each tab to have different colors. I tried that in many ways but didn't work. This is the output I got till now.

[image]

What I want is given below.

[image]

This is my code.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

const initialLayout = {
    height: 0,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
};

const FirstRoute = () => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, styles.FirstRouteStyle]} />
    );
};

const SecondRoute = () => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, styles.SecondRouteStyle]} />
    );
};

const ThirdRoute = () => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, styles.ThirdRouteStyle]} />
    );
};


export default class TabView extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        index: 0,
        routes: [
            { key: 'first', title: 'First', tabStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' } },
            { key: 'second', title: 'Second', tabStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' } },
            { key: 'third', title: 'Third', tabStyle: { backgroundColor: 'blue' } },
        ],
    };

    _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });


    _renderScene = SceneMap({
        first: FirstRoute,
        second: SecondRoute,
        third: ThirdRoute,
    });

    _renderHeader(props) {
        return (
            <TabBar
                {...props}
                style={styles.tabbar}
                tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
                labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
            />
        )
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <TabViewAnimated
                style={styles.container}
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
                initialLayout={initialLayout}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    FirstRouteStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff4081'
    },
    SecondRouteStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#673ab7'
    },
    ThirdRouteStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    },
    tabbar: {
        //backgroundColor: 'green',
        height: 100,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    tabStyle: {

    },
    labelStyle: {

    },
    tablabel: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 12,
        margin: 4,
    }
};
```

As I have studied tabStyle can be used to style individual tabs. I used that but it didn't work. Please help me to add different colors as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `tabStyle` sets the style for every tab, the `<TabBar>` component is expecting no prop to handle the style per tab individually.

You can achieve this by implementing your own TabBar, that you can return from you `renderHeader`. Basically just grab [the existing TabBar component](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/blob/master/src/TabBar.js), paste it in your project, update according to your styling needs, import and use in your `TabView` instead of the standard TabBar.

Comment: Could you please explain it more?

Comment: Not really sure about the way to describe it in more details. Copy-paste the existing TabBar component from github into your project and use it as if it was your custom TabBar. You are now doing `import { TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view'`, after you have the component copied, you can do `import TabBar` from 'the-place-you-copied-the-tabbar-to'. After that you'll be able to edit tabbar and change colors since you'll have it locally. Let me know which part it unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to achieve it using button groups. This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'react-native-elements';

const component1 = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
const component2 = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
            <Text>World</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
const component3 = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
            <Text>ButtonGroup</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0
        }
        this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this)
    }
    updateIndex(selectedIndex) {
        this.setState({ selectedIndex })
    }

    render() {
        const buttons = [{ element: component1 }, { element: component2 }, { element: component3 }]
        const { selectedIndex } = this.state
        if (selectedIndex === 0) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ButtonGroup
                        onPress={this.updateIndex}
                        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                        buttons={buttons}
                        containerStyle={{ height: 100 }}
                    />
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', width: '100%', height: 500 }} />
                </View>
             );
        } else if (selectedIndex === 1) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ButtonGroup
                        onPress={this.updateIndex}
                        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                        buttons={buttons}
                        containerStyle={{ height: 100 }}
                    />
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'purple', width: '100%', height: 500 }} />
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ButtonGroup
                        onPress={this.updateIndex}
                        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                        buttons={buttons}
                        containerStyle={{ height: 100 }}
                    />
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', width: '100%', height: 500 }} />
                </View>
            );
        }

    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testApp', () => App);
```